# Lapack error with SGETRF

Tags: lapack

I am using `LAPACK library` to solve an optimization problem. I am getting different Lapack errors `(Lapack error(1,2,3,4) with SGETRF)`. Is there any documentation source, which I can read to understand what exactly these errors mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of Lapack routines return an error code in the argument `INFO`. The meaning of this output is specified in the documentation of the function [`sgetrf()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-3.1.1-html/sgetrf.f.html)

If INFO is null, then everething is OK !
If INFO <0 , an error was detected in the input parameters. For instance, for `sgetrf()`:

- INFO=-1 : number of rows of the matrix is negative
- INFO=-2 : number of columns of the matrix is negative
- INFO=-4  : LDA is lower than MAX( 1, M )

The routine `xerbla()` can be applied to print the right error message:

```
XERBLA( 'SGETRF', -INFO )
```

If INFO>0, the document clearly describes what is happening :

> U(i,i) is exactly zero. The factorization has been completed, but the factor U is exactly singular, and division by zero will occur if it is used
>   to solve a system of equations.

This problem can occur if the matrix is singular or ill-conditionned. If the matrix `A` is singular, there might be different solutions, or no solution at all to the problem `Ax=b`. 
If INFO=1, it is likely that the matrix is null.

Hence, testing `INFO` is to be considered as a good practice as functions such as `sgetrf()` or `sgesv()` are called...